# TortoiseGit equivalence for 'TortoiseSVN --> Show log --> Revert to this revision'

Tags: git, svn, tortoisesvn, tortoisegit

I am looking for a TortoiseGit operation which is equivalent to:

```
TortoiseSVN --> Show log --> Revert to this revision
```

In TortoiseSVN, this operation reverts the local repository to the revision selected, while keeping all changed files checked out.

In other words, the changed files show up when I do `TortoiseSVN --> Check for modifications`, and I can easily discard those changes when I finish testing the revision that I have reverted to.

For some reason, I am finding it very difficult to perform this useful operation on TortoiseGit.

The workaround that I am currently using is:

1. Perform `TortoiseGit --> Show log --> Export this revision...`
2. Copy the output files onto my local repository

Is there a more straightforward manner for this?

I've tried the following TortoiseGit operations, but they just "cause havoc" on my local repository, and I am unable to proceed with the "standard" Commit & Push procedure afterwards:

- `Reset "master" to this...`
- `Switch/Checkout to this...`
- `Rebase "master" onto this...`
- `Revert change by this commit`

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35492990/how-do-i-check-out-an-older-version-of-a-file-with-tortoisegit), but the answers suggest options that are not even viable in my TortoiseGit popup menu.

Comment: Been a while since I used subversion, but here's an example, let's say you in commit #1 have a file containing A, then at commit #2 you changed it to B. Now you revert to #1, does the file now contain B or A?

Comment: Did you try "git checkout" ? You say it cause havoc, what does that mean exactly? But my previous question, answer that first and we'll take it from there.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: I don't have that option in the TortoiseGit popup menu.

Comment: That "switch/checkout to this" is probably the one I ask for, but please answer my first question about A vs. B, it will help me understand what kind of operation you're looking for.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Thank you. The file on my local machine contains A, and the file in GIT contains B. The file name therefore shows up when I do `TortoiseGit --> Check for modifications` (i.e., it is "checked out" on my local machine, and I can revert the changes or commit/push them).

Answer (score 3):

1. Right click on the commit, then `Compare with working tree`
   [image]
2. Select all files expect `Added` ones and `Rename` ones, and Right click, and `Revert to revert xxxxxxx(sha1)`
   [image]
3. For `Added` ones, you need to deleted them manually
4. For `Renamed` ones, you need to rename them back manually
5. Back to the `Changed Files` and refresh it to see if it is `No differences found!`
   [image]
6. Commit
   [image]
7. The log
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

I found another batter way than I answered before, and **you don't care about `Renamed` and `added` itme(s) in this way**:

1. Select all commits you want to revert, and right click on them, and click `Revert changes by these commits`

   [image]
2. Will be a progress dialog

   [image]
3. Then, ask you if perform the Commit. Click `Commit`

   [image]
4. The commit dialog:

   [image]
   But, as you can see, TortoiseGit gives out one sha1 value, instead of all commit sha1 values you want to revert. So you may be want to add/modify more information there. Like this:
   [image]
5. The log of that **revert commit**

   [image]